# Issues with getting cuda to work on torch, importing torch and cuda modules into Python

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, cuda

I'm having some basic issues running the torch and cuda modules in my Python script.

I think that this has something to do with the different versions of Python that I have installed. I have two versions of Python installed:

[image]

I think I have torch and cuda installed for the wrong one or something. I don't know how to fix this.

Per the Pytorch website, I installed torch as follows:
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`

I've installed cuda as follows: `pip3 install cuda-python==11.7` (It doesn't matter if I use the newest version -- I still get the same results.)

When I look up the versions, I get the following:
[image]

So it seems like it is all installed correctly.

However, if I run the following:

```
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I get `False`.

If I try to run my code that uses torch, I get the following error:
[image]

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. As far as I can tell, I've installed torch with CUDA enabled. So I'm not sure why it's telling me otherwise.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Edit: Here is the info for my GPU:
[image]

Comment: @talonmies The thing is... I don't think I did. I followed the exact instructions it says here https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ for CUDA 11.7. That's this line: `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`

Comment: The thing is that you have two different python interpreters and it looks like two different python library installations. What you show at the top of your question is pytorch installed within an anaconda installation and what you show at the bottom is pytorch within a different installation. It looks to me like you have two Pytorch versions installed and one of them isn't compiled with GPU support, and that one is the one you are trying to use. Look at the paths, they don't match

Comment: Also, not important, but you don't need to install cuda-python. That is a set of low level programmatic bindings to the CUDA driver API and JIT compiler. It isn't used by Pytorch and won't help you here at all

Comment: Do I have to install any python packages related to CUDA? Or do I just need to install NVIDIA CUDA from their website?

Comment: It depends. Anaconda will install a package which includes the matching version of the CUDA runtime components for Pytorch. I don't know what pip does and what that bundle includes. A matching driver must be installed by you (but you have that already so  nothing is required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the different versions of Python. I ended up using a Conda virtual environment, which solved this issue by ensuring I was using the correct version of Pytorch.